# PLSQL Access Different Schema

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a PL/SQL routine that needs to access multiple databases; my dev environment is Oracle XE & Eclipse with Toad.  I have granted select permission to the user (in this case SAMPLES) on the other schema (in this case CORE.SAMPLE) so that a query such as :

```
SELECT count(*) from core.sample;
```

When run as the user SAMPLES works just fine.  However I then have a procedure in a package as such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CORE_SEARCH
AS
    FUNCTION search_barcode (barcode IN VARCHAR2)
        RETURN BOOLEAN
    IS
        num_lines   INT;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT (*)
        INTO num_lines
        FROM CORE.SAMPLE s
        WHERE s.barcode = barcode;

        RETURN num_lines > 0;
    END;
END;
/
```

I'm using TOAD and toad complains that CORE.SAMPLE is not available and when I try to compile it in the Oracle DB (in the SAMPLES schema) it doesn't work.  I get the infamous 'PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist' however I know that the SAMPLES user can access core.sample as the raw SQL statement works so why doesn't the stored procedure.  This is how I call the stored procedure to test:

```
begin
    CORE_SEARCH.SEARCH_BARCODE('test');
end;
```

Again this is run as the SAMPLES user who has select privilege on the CORE.SAMPLE table.

Can someone please help as to why this is happening; thanks.

Neil

Comment: how did you grant the select on your core.sample table to the samples user? Was it a direct grant, or was it granted to a role, which was then granted to the samples user?

Comment: Interestingly I initially granted a role which didn't work on the simple sql statement so I then granted it directly and the simple sql statement worked.

Comment: you can give a try to create synonym and check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by removing a role previously granted which gave the select privilege on the table and the user also had select privilege on the table.  Just the user works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are calling the procedure from SAMPLES you need to add the owner of the package when calling it (assuming thats CORE) :

CORE.CORE_SEARCH.SEARCH_BARCODE('test');

Comment: it is owned by samples